# No entiendo por qué esta variable no es una String

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo Java y no entiendo por qué, aparentemente, la variable `MiColor`no se convierte en una String.

```js
public class Vendedor {
    static Recuperacolor MiColor;
    static Recuperafigura MiFigura;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

 MiColor = Recuperacolor.PreguntaColor();
 System.out.println("Genial! Has elegido " + MiColor + ".");
 
 int PrecioColor = Recuperacolor.getPrecio(MiColor); 
    }
}
```

Al ejecutarse la linea `"Genial! Has elegido " + MiColor + "."` lo hace como una String, sin embargo cuando intento usarla como argumento para la función `getPrecio`:

public class Recuperacolor {

```
    public static int getPrecio(String color) {
        switch(color) {
            case "NARANJA":
                return 2;
            case "AZUL":
                return 1;
            case "ROJO":
                return 1;
            case "VERDE":
                return 2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Me da error: "The method getPrecio(String) in the type Recuperacolor is not applicable for the arguments (Recuperacolor)"

He intentado, para probar simplemente asignar esto:

```
String EstoDeberiaSerUnaString = Recuperacolor.PreguntaColor();
```

Y sin embargo dice que "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Recuperacolor to String"

Answer (score 3):

Para lo primero, el problema es que la función  `getPrecio()` tiene que recibir un parametro de Tipo String, sin embargo, `MiColor` es de tipo `Recuperacolor`. Por eso te da ese mensaje de "Recuperacolor is not applicable for the arguments" por que no es el tipo de dato esperado por la función.